# Get Duplicate values count using LINQ c#

Tags: c#, linq

I want to get the duplicate values count from one table. The input values are like as below,

1. SUB -xxx-20160721
2. SUB -xxx-20160721
3. SUB -125-20160022

Here (1) and (2) are same value. If the Name is more than 1 it should return 1 as a result. the result should return the count as (2).

```
 var numberOfDuplicates = this.UnitOfWork.Repository<Models.SUB>()
            .Queryable().GroupBy(x => x.Name)
            .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
            .Select(x => x.Count());
```

**The result is**

2
2
2
2
2
3
2
2
4

Please guide me on this..

Comment: What is expected output?

Answer (score 3):

The return value of the below code is an anonymous object with 2 properties:

- `Value` The value that is duplicate
- `Amount` The amount of times it is duplicate

```
var numberOfDuplicates = this.UnitOfWork.Repository()
    .Queryable().GroupBy(x => x.Name)
    .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
    .Select(x => new { Value = x.Key, Amount = x.Count() } );
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you're returning the `Count` of each group using the `Select(x=> x.Count())` statement.

You can return the Name (The `Key` of Grouping) and the Count using anonymous types:

```
 var numberOfDuplicates = this.UnitOfWork.Repository<Models.SUB>()
            .Queryable().GroupBy(x => x.Name)
            .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
            .Select(x => new { Name = x.Key, Count = x.Count() });

foreach(var dup in numberOfDuplicates)
{
     Console.WriteLine($"Name = {dup.Name } ** Counter = {dup.Count}");
}
```

Results:

```
Name = 1.SUB -xxx-20160721 ** Count = 2
```